# Excluded dates from a recurring events are not excluded when imported in google calendar

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I'm exporting a recurring events where i specify some excluded dates. This is how i specify them

```
EXDATE:20121202T230000Z,20121204T230000Z,20121206T230000Z
```

They are in Zulu ( GMT ) time. I f import the same event in outlook the exclusion works as expected.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is your DTSTART? is that a DATETIME or just a DATE? also what is your RRULE?
trying with below it worked on google calendar:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
PRODID:ical2list
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20121201T230000Z
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY
UID:so13662467
DTSTAMP:20121201T230000Z
EXDATE:20121202T230000Z,20121204T230000Z,20121206T230000Z
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: DTSTART is a date for me, i ended up using google version which uses multiple EXDATES like this
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20121201
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20121202
EXDATE;VALUE=DATE:20121212
EXDATE;VALUE=DATE:20121210
EXDATE;VALUE=DATE:20121214

Comment: makes also sense as if the type of the DTSTART and EXDATE is different (DATE vs DATETIME) the exclusion does not work.

Comment: You are right, the type of EXDATE and DTSTART must match. And when DTSTART is in Datetime, exclude dates must match the Time part too, like this DTSTART;TZID=America/Vancouver:20121130T013000
DTEND;TZID=America/Vancouver:20121130T030000
EXDATE;TZID=America/Vancouver:20121210T013000
EXDATE;TZID=America/Vancouver:20121212T013000
EXDATE;TZID=America/Vancouver:20121214T013000

Comment: One more thing, if you are setting a timezone, the start time of the exception date MUST match the start time of DTSTART. So this works
`DTSTART;TZID=America/Vancouver:20140505T084500
DTEND;TZID=America/Vancouver:20140505T094500
EXDATE;TZID=America/Vancouver:20140516T084500,20140523T084500,20140530T084500`